# Ansible [unclear] dependency error causing pain

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ansible

Suddenly this morning, new ansible project just dosent work anymore...

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.8) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
```

But if i do `pip3 list |grep "chardet"` or `pip3 list |grep "chardet"` they will be exactly the asked versions... (localhost)

```
ansible --version | grep "python version"
```

tells me im indeed using python 3.6

and `ansible --version`
is 2.9.4

what the..

EDIT:
Even tho i have python3, and ansible *says* it's using python3, it is NOT...

running with -vvv tells me, ansible is *still* using python 2.7.....

How do i change this?

```
  python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) [GCC 7.4.0]
```

this is quite ridiculous...

Comment: You are checking on your localhost (ansible controler). The error is on your target.

Answer (score 0):

Yep,
Im pretty eager to say its ansibles fault.

Ansible simply will always try to run usr/bin/python instead of /usr/bin/python3 and then fails.

**use python3 /usr/bin/ansible-playbook**